# can't update a row in android sqlite

Tags: java, android, sqlite, sql-update

i tried to update a row in one table on my sqlite first time i tried to update as below :

```
    public void updateMasterSPAJ(
            String nama_pp,
            String gelar_pp,
            String ibu_pp,
            String hubungan_pp,
            int spinner_hubungan_pp 
        ) {
    ContentValues cv=new ContentValues();
        cv.put("nama_pp", nama_pp);
        cv.put("gelar_pp", gelar_pp);
        cv.put("ibu_pp", ibu_pp);
        cv.put("hubungan_pp", hubungan_pp);
        cv.put("spinner_hubungan_pp", spinner_hubungan_pp); 
    getWritableDatabase().update("pemegang_polis", cv, "SPAJ_ID=SPAJ_ID", null);
}
```

but this code will update all row, not a specific row, so i change my code in this line `getWritableDatabase().update("pemegang_polis", cv, "SPAJ_ID=SPAJ_ID", null);` 
into

```
`getWritableDatabase().update("pemegang_polis", cv, "pemegang_polis.SPAJ_ID=master_spaj.SPAJ_ID", null);`
```

i got error, and this is my logcat says:

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: master_spaj.SPAJ_ID (code 1): , while compiling: UPDATE pemegang_polis SET spinner_hubungan_pp=?,ibu_pp=?,hubungan_pp=?,nama_pp=?,gelar_pp=? WHERE pemegang_polis.SPAJ_ID=master_spaj.SPAJ_ID
```

and then i change that line into :

```
    a=Menu_SPPAJ.getX();
    getWritableDatabase().update("pemegang_polis", cv, "SPAJ_ID="+ a, null);
```

because value from `SPAJ_ID` from `pemegang_polis` is gotten from class `Menu_SPPAJ.getX()` . i  got error again, and this is my logcat says :

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near ".01": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: UPDATE pemegang_polis SET spinner_hubungan_pp=?,ibu_pp=?,hubungan_pp=?,nama_pp=?,gelar_pp=? WHERE SPAJ_ID=AndroidESPAJ2014.01.12.04.20.04.568
```

i don't know where's my fault, i think everything is fine, is there something that i miss or anything else? i hope someone understand my problem, can help me to solve my problem, thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near ".01": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: UPDATE pemegang_polis SET spinner_hubungan_pp=?,ibu_pp=?,hubungan_pp=?,nama_pp=?,gelar_pp=? WHERE SPAJ_ID=AndroidESPAJ2014.01.12.04.20.04.568

The `SPAJ_ID` value `AndroidESPAJ2014.01.12.04.20.04.568` looks like a string literal but is not quoted like a `'string literal'`.

However, it's better to use `?` literal placeholder and bind arguments instead:

```
getWritableDatabase().update("pemegang_polis", cv, "SPAJ_ID=?", new String[] { a });
```

Comment: You answered better than me. +1 to your answer for the preparedstatement stuff.

Comment: @laalto i've tried your code and there is no row that have updated.

Comment: @AoyamaNanami Then you'll have to figure out the `where` condition you'll need to use with your data in your database. All we can use is the information provided in your question.

Comment: i prefer to use SPAJ_ID=master_spaj.SPAJ_ID but i always get errors that said no such column: master_spaj.SPAJ_ID

Comment: Yes, that makes no sense since there's no table or table alias by the name `master_spaj` in the query.

Answer (score 1):

The third parameter of update() is meant to hold the where condition.

Your first attempt `"SPAJ_ID=SPAJ_ID"` is true for all the row since every row has a value in every column that matches...itself.

If your condition includes checking the SPAJ_ID column against a given value just use:

"SPAJ_ID="+yourVal

where yourVal is the ID you want to use for filtering. Remember to include quotes if your ID is of String type.

In case of a String type just use:

```
"SPAJ_ID='"+yourVal+"'"
```

Comment: i have tried your method with "SPAJ_ID="+ a but i got an error

Comment: Because you missed the quotes.

Comment: You should set yourValue at the value of the id you want to update. Also be sure to actually set different values than the one currently in the Db.